# After Magento 1.9 SUPEE-9767 allow pdf upload not working - Invalid Mime Type

Tags: magento-1.9

I used this modification to allow upload of PDF files into magento
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/155950/40025

After applying SUPEE-9767 Upload does not work anymore and got Message "Invalid Mime Type"

How to allow PDF upload after SUPEE-9767 Patch?

Comment: According to the patch analysis describe here [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176871/security-patch-supee-9767-possible-issues)  the patch modifies the upload facility.  So have a read of that and you'll possibly get some clues.

Answer (score 10):

I created a module to help fix the problem. Hopefully, it helps others who come across this same issue.

[Ash_PdfUploadAfterSupee9767 on Github](https://github.com/augustash/ash_pdfuploadaftersupee9767)

**Overrides:**

- `Mage_Core_Model_File_Validator_Image` (skips validation if mime type is `application/pdf`)
- `Mage_Cms_Model_Wysiwyg_Images_Storage` (skips resizing if mime type is `application/pdf`)
- Adds `pdf` to array of `allowed` and `image_allowed` extensions from the `Mage_Cms/etc/config.xml`

Comment: Works as intended, although I used my own class names and removed the adminhtml stuff... I just left it always on.

Comment: this works, though I see that the editor adds <img src=""> when a PDF is uploaded. is there a way to make it work for ppl who have no HTML knowledge?

Answer (score 2):

Following Rakesh's Answer you could extend the validate() function in \app\code\local\Mage\Core\Model\File\Validator\Image.php from

```
                imagedestroy($img);
                imagedestroy($image);
                return null;
            } else {
                throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid image.'));
            }
        }
    }
```

to

```
                imagedestroy($img);
                imagedestroy($image);
                return null;
            } else {
                throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid image.'));
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (mime_content_type($filePath)=='application/pdf') {
            $fileType = IMAGETYPE_PNG;          
            return null;
        }               
        throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid MIME type.').' '.mime_content_type($filePath));
    }
```

Tested in Magento CE 1.9.2.4. The extended answer in German you can find [here](https://www.econcess.de/blog/10-onlineshop-erstellung-magento/127-magento-pdf-upload-invalid-mime-type-nach-supee-9767).

Answer (score 0):

There is a new validation added to uplaodeFile function (app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php) which doesn't allow PDF to get uploaded even after adding `<pdf>1</pdf>` to CMS Browsers extensions node.

Here is the new validation

```
    $uploader->addValidateCallback(
        Mage_Core_Model_File_Validator_Image::NAME,
        Mage::getModel('core/file_validator_image'),
        'validate'
    );
```

This additional validation check for file types that are defined in class

```
Mage_Core_Model_File_Validator_Image
```

Below is the list of allowed images types that can be uploaded via WYSIWYG insert Image action.

IMAGETYPE_JPEG,IMAGETYPE_GIF,
IMAGETYPE_JPEG2000,
IMAGETYPE_PNG,
IMAGETYPE_ICO,
IMAGETYPE_TIFF_II,
IMAGETYPE_TIFF_MM

So, Basically in order to allow PDF upload

1. Extends  Mage_Core_Model_File_Validator_Image::validate and add custom logic to allow PDF upload
2. Create a new extension that will allow PDF upload.

Comment: The problem with the new SUPEE-9767 validation is that it seems to apply the image validation regardless of whether one is inserting a link, media or image. 

For example, you'll also now hit the 'invalid mime type' error if you try and upload a .mov file using the 'Insert/Edit Embedded media' wysiwyg button, as it goes through the same validation.

The ideal fix would presumably be to only push the upload through the new validation if one is uploading an image?